# MySQL default DATETIME field with an offset

Tags: mysql, oracle

When `CREATE TABLE` , how to set MySQL `DATETIME` field with an default offset??

In `oracle`, I can do something like:

```
PWDEXPIRETIME" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE+30 NOT NULL ENABLE
```

But it gives me an error when do this in MYSQL:

```
PWDEXPIRETIME` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP+30 NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL versions earlier than 8+, then the most you can do is to specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, with no offset, as the default value.

In [MySQL 8+](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html), you may use `INTERVAL` syntax to get what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (
    PWDEXPIRETIME DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE),
    ...
)
```

Comment: In Oracle, `SYSDATE+30` is adding 30 days so the equivalent would be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 30 DAY` (and you can do the same in Oracle but you need quotes around the numeric value like this: `SYSDATE + INTERVAL '30' DAY`)